# SSH into digitalocean server from circleci

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean, circleci

I’m trying to introduce some automation via circleci where it will go into the server made in digitalocean via ssh in order to put in commands for updating said server. I’m not quite sure how to do that. If I start with the straight ssh IP ADDRESS command, it will hold on

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
The authenticity of host ‘IP ADDRESS (IP ADDRESS)’ can’t be established.

It is supposed to ask if I want to continue connecting and I would answer yes, but that doesn’t appear until after it has failed, so not even adding in yes | to the command will work. I’ve also tried generating an ssh key that I can then add to the list of accepted ssh keys in digitalocean, but since I can’t interact with it, I can’t follow the prompts that follow the ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C command. Does anybody have any ideas? I am most certainly stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To SSH from CircleCI into Digital Ocean, you need to do several things:

### Key management

- Create an SSH key. Add the public key to the `./ssh/authorized_keys` file on your DO server for the user you plan to use.
- Add your private key in your CircleCi projects settings, in the *SSH Keys* section, in the *Additional SSH Keys* panel. Click on *Add SSH Key*, leave the *Hostname* empty (important) and paste your key.
- Copy the fingerprint of your key.

### Inject your private key in your CircleCI instance

In your `.circleci/Config.yml` config file, add a step to inject your private key to your CircleCi instance:

```
- add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:
            - "[ADD  YOUR SSH FINGERPRINT HERE]"
```

### Disregard SSH warnings

Modify the ssh client config before using it to disregard warnings:

```
 - run:
          name: SSH into DO
          command: |
              echo "disregard ssh known_hosts warnings"
              echo "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" > ~/.ssh/config
              echo "StrictHostKeyChecking=no">> ~/.ssh/config
              ssh something something
```

Comment: It would say that the private key is invalid when I tried to add it to the project settings. I was able to get everything else though.

Comment: Wait. Just found out about the keygen pem thing. I'll let you know if I have additional questions.

Comment: Not sure what happened there. But I added in the private key with the pem version of keygen, I added that private key to the circleci project settings with a blank hostname, added the new fingerprint to the code as you described, updated the authorized keys file with the public key, and also added it to my digitalocean security settings. When trying to use circleci, I get Disregard SSH known_hosts warnings.

Warning: Permanently added 'IP ADDRESS' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Authentication failed.

Exited with code exit status 255

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: turns out I just needed to add root@ to the ssh command. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!

Comment: So it seems I was only able to perform the command once with ssh root@IP "ls". After that I can't seem to do it anymore. Is there something I need to add for subsequent uses like clearing out the config file in .ssh or something? I would get 
Disregard SSH known_hosts warnings.

Warning: Permanently added 'IP' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).

Exited with code exit status 255